# Date Change with VBA Excel add/subtract in two different cells

Tags: excel, vba

How can I create a macro that will add a day in one cell and subtract a day in another cell at the same time?  Here is what I have so far.

```
Sub ChangeDates()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("B:B")
    cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
Next cell

For Each cell In Range("C:C")

    cell.Value = cell.Value - 1

End Sub
```

Comment: why do you need VBA to do this? You can use Excel formulas for this very easily.

Comment: Because I want the auto - run the macro on the workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offset to the rescue!!

```
Sub ChangeDates()  
Dim cell As Range  
   For Each cell In Range("B:B")     
      cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
      cell.offset(0,1).value = cell.offset(0,1).value - 1
   Next cell  
End Sub
```

Another thing you may consider is either looking at usedrange to not have to iterate through all of column B or put in a check to make sure the cells aren't blank... Just faster, better coding and stops you from having bad values where the cells were originally blank...

```
Sub ChangeDates()
Dim cell As Range
   For Each cell In Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
      cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
      cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value - 1
   Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: what if... for example B46 is empty and B50 is not what statement can I use to continue the change?

Answer (score 3):

I know you've accepted an answer, but I would like to offer this approach, which is even faster and more efficient than looping through all those cells.

If your dates are in Column A, then Column B will hold `date +1` and Column C will hold `date -1`

```
Option Explicit
Sub ChangeDates()

Dim myRange As range
Dim mySheet As Worksheet

Set mySheet = Sheets("Sheet7") 'change to your sheet

With mySheet

    Set myRange = .range("A1:A" & .range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    myRange.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+1"
    myRange.Offset(, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-1"

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott that works also... I really appreciate the help.

Comment: It works, yes. But the key is that it is much faster. I don't know your programming level, but you will come to appreciate over time that looping is often not the most efficient solution. By eliminating looping I once helped code move from over 1+ hours to execute to less than 10 mins!