# Using R1C1 formula in VBSCRIPT

Tags: excel, vbscript, sas

I create a excel document with SAS using VBSCRIPT. Here is the code that work :

```
    filename vbscript "&fich_trim..vbs";

    DATA _NULL_;

        FILE vbscript;

        PUT "Dim Exc, Classeur";
        put "Dim Col";
        PUT "Set Exc = CreateObject(""Excel.Application"")";
        PUT "Exc.Visible = False";
        PUT "Set Classeur = Exc.Workbooks.Open (""&FICH_trim..XML"")";

        do i = 4 to (&nb_ins.*2) by 2;
            put 'Classeur.Worksheets(1).Cells(73,' i ').formula = "=SUM(D6:D69)-D70"';
            *put 'Classeur.Worksheets(1).Cells(73,' i ').formulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R(-67)C:R(-4)C)-R(-3)C"';
        end;


        PUT "Classeur.Saveas (""&fich_trim..xls""),1";
        PUT "Exc.Quit";
    RUN;

    option noxwait xsync;
    %SYSEXEC "&fich_trim..VBS";
    %sysexec del "&fich_trim..vbs";
    %sysexec del "&fich_trim..xml";
```

My main problem is in the loop statement. As you can see in my loop I have a line in comment where I'm trying to use the R1C1 formula instead of the standard form of excel formula. When I use the R1C1 line it give me an error. I would prefer to use the R1C1 standart because in my loop I would like the easily specify "(SUM((D+i)6:(D+i)69)" and I dont really know how to do so easily so I figure out that the R1C1 standart is the easiest way.

thank you for your time!

Comment: My suggestion: put the R1C1 formula into excel (turning Excel temporarily into the R1C1 format in settings) and get it right there.

Comment: See [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165938/what-is-the-function-of-formular1c1) for more details on how to use this properly, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primarily your problem is R1C1 formulas use [ ] brackets.

So, your formula is probably:

```
=SUM(R[-67]C:R[-4]C)-R[-3]C
```

Comment: Yes, for releative references.

Comment: But btw in Excel the formula was only with "(" and ")" and Excel was able to interpret it.

Comment: Yes, paren for formula brackets for refs.