# Don't understand excel formula embedded in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please explain this Excel formula inside the VBA code.

```
Range("U8").FormulaR1C1 = _
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'C:\temp\MasterRecords.xls'!C2:C15,14,FALSE)=""True""),""No Title Found"",VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'C:\temp\MasterRecords.xls'!C2:C15,14,FALSE))"
```

I get that the `IF` is checking for the `#N/A` value. What I don't understand is what either of the `VLOOKUP`functions is doing exactly. What cell are being reference by the R1C1 notation? Why doesn't the column need to be specified? Then I don't get the `'C:\temp\MasterRecords.xls'!C2:C15` arguments. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the function of FormulaR1C1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165938/what-is-the-function-of-formular1c1)

Comment: Because C2:C15 means 14 cells in xlA1 syntax and 14,680,064
 cells in xlR1C1 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In the formula

1) RC[-1] refers to the one cell left to the formula cell.

2) The Vlookup formula is referring to an external workbook C:\temp\MasterRecords.xls.

3) table_array C2:C15 used in Vlookup formula refers to $B:$O

4) Col_index_num 14 refers to the column O considering the table_array

The formula is written in R1C1 style and I suppose you are getting confused with C2:C15 because R is missing that only means here that whole columns are used in the formula i.e. $B:$O

Answer (score 0):

Looking through what you have written lets break down the vlookup:

```
VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'C:\temp\MasterRecords.xls'!C2:C15,14,FALSE)
```

`RC[-1]` = Lookup the value in 1 column to the left of current cell. (same row)

`'C:\temp\MasterRecords.xls'!C2:C15` = Look for the data in C2:C15 (column 2 to column 15 of the masterRecords xl file.

`14` = Returns the 14th column in the lookup range. Will return column 15 of the file.

`FALSE` = exact match.