# Define range by a cell value for several columns Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of data of over 1500 rows spread into several columns. I want to find the minimum of different parameters in each column (for each column there are 5 parameters and I want to find the minimum from each one). I've written a VBA code with the help of macro:

```
Sub MinimumValue()
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Parameter"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "300"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "700"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1000"
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1200"
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1600"
    '' stating the parameters

    Dim s1 As String
    Dim s2 As String
    Dim s3 As String
    Dim s4 As String
    Dim s5 As String

    s1 = Range("H1")
    s2 = Range("I1")
    s3 = Range("J1")
    s4 = Range("K1")
    s5 = Range("L1")

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(Sheet1!B1:s1)"
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(Sheet1!s1:s2)"
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(Sheet1!s2:s3)"
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(Sheet1!s3:s4)"
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(Sheet1!s4:s5)"
    Range("B1:B6").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B1:J6").Select
```

I wanted to paste the different minimum values on another worksheet and tried to state a string that translates to a range of cell where the value is taken from a cell itself, but it's telling me #NONAME because it cannot identify s1, s2, s3, and s4. I tried a formula with indirect and concatenate, it worked but only for one column and I need it for several columns which will take a lot of time to manually rewrite them.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Because s1 is a variable and you are trying to use it in a string as a literal...not a variable

Comment: Yes. You would need to assign `s1 = "H1"` and use it like `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(Sheet1!B1:" &  s1 & ")"`

Comment: Please also try not to use `.Select` its not necessary for your operations instead just say `Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Parameter"`

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of things can make your code better, but to make it workable, try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MinimumValue()

    Dim s1 As String
    Dim s2 As String
    Dim s3 As String
    Dim s4 As String
    Dim s5 As String

    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Parameter"
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "300"
    Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "700"
    Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "1000"
    Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "1200"
    Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "1600"

    s1 = Range("H1")
    s2 = Range("I1")
    s3 = Range("J1")
    s4 = Range("K1")
    s5 = Range("L1")

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    Range("B1").Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!B1:s1)"
    Range("B2").Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!s1:s2)"
    Range("B3").Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!s2:s3)"
    Range("B4").Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!s3:s4)"
    Range("B5").Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!s4:s5)"

    Range("B1:B6").Select
    Range("B1:B6").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B1:J6").Select

End Sub
```

You should use `ActiveCell.Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!s1:s2)"` instead of `FormulaR1C1`. [What is the function of FormulaR1C1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165938/what-is-the-function-of-formular1c1)

**Edit:**

To use the `s1`, `s2` ... `s5` as addresses, amend the code to the following:

```
Range("B1").Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!B1:" & s1 & ")"
Range("B2").Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!B1:" & s2 & ")"
```

Comment: Additional side note: You really should [avoid using select and activate](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate) ([VBA Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices)).

Comment: @Peh - true, point taken. Still, the code can be improved further.

Comment: I used ActiveCell.Formula = "=MIN(Tabelle1!s1:s2)" instead of FormulaR1C1. It almost worked where I had real integers now but I what the s1, s2, s3, and s4 to be the range for example in the first minimum =MIN(Sheet1!B1:s1) I want s1 to be actually B300 and s2 B700 and so on and it continues for the other columns for example C1:s1 which is actually the range C1:C300

Answer (score 0):

It would be more like this, to make use of the variables.

```
Sub MinimumValue()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

    Range("A1").Value = "Parameter"
    Range("B1").Value = "300"
    Range("C1").Value = "700"
    Range("D1").Value = "1000"
    Range("E1").Value = "1200"
    Range("F1").Value = "1600"


    Dim s1 As String
    Dim s2 As String
    Dim s3 As String
    Dim s4 As String
    Dim s5 As String

    s1 = "H1"
    s2 = "I1"
    s3 = "J1"
    s4 = "K1"
    s5 = "L1"

   Set sht = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
   Set rng = sht.Range("B1:B6")

    With sht
    .Range("B1").Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!B1:" & s1 & ")"
    .Range("B2").Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!" & s1 & ":" & s2 & ")"
    .Range("B3").Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!" & s2 & ":" & s3 & ")"
    .Range("B4").Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!" & s3 & ":" & s4 & ")"
    .Range("B5").Formula = "=MIN(Sheet1!" & s4 & ":" & s5 & ")"
    End With
    rng.AutoFill Destination:=Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight))
End Sub
```