# VBA with Vlookup function

Tags: vba, excel

I am having two sheets, Sht1 and sht2. With sht1, I always look into column B and check if the ID are matching with column B of sht2, if they are matching then , I copy the column Q value of sht1 to sht2.

I tried accomplishing through the below code, and I am not able to get the result, There is no error shown in the code.

I am lost what is wrong with my code. Could anyone help me to get rid of this.

```
Sub vlookupComments()
Dim totalrows As Long, totalrowsSht2  As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
totalrows = Sheets("sht1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
totalrowsSht2 = Sheets("sht2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("sht1").Range("Q5:Q" & totalrows).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Sheets("sht1").Range("B5:B" & totalrowsSht2), Sheets("sht2").Range("$A:$Q"), 17, 0), "")
End Sub
```

Comment: you are using iferror in formula. it is replacing error with **""** blank value

Comment: @MaddyNikam how do I rectify that

Comment: Do you want the result in column Q to be a formula, or the value ?

Comment: the column Q should have the result of formula

Comment: @ShaiRado am I clear or confusing you ?

Comment: Not clear, you want to have a formula there, which will return a value. Or a clean value (without a formula in the cell) ?

Comment: I want to have a clean.value.. without formula in the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says "copy column Q value of sht1 to sht2" but the formula does the other way. I go with the formula,

Try the below macro,

```
Sub vlookupComments()
Dim totalrows As Long, totalrowsSht2  As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
totalrows = Sheets("sht1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
totalrowsSht2 = Sheets("sht2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To totalrows
    Sheets("sht1").Cells(i, "Q").Value = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("sht1").Cells(i, "B"), _
    Sheets("sht2").Range("A1:Q" & totalrowsSht2), 17, 0)
Next i
End Sub
```

Option2:

```
Sub lookupmaturitystart()
Dim totalrows As Long, totalrowsSht2 As Long
totalrows = Sheets("Maturity_BU").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
totalrowsSht2 = Sheets("Maturity_Lastweek").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To totalrows
For j = 1 To totalrowsSht2
If Sheets("Maturity_BU").Cells(i, "B") = Sheets("Maturity_Lastweek").Cells(j, "B") Then
    Sheets("Maturity_BU").Cells(i, "Q") = Sheets("Maturity_Lastweek").Cells(j, "Q")
End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I will give this a try.. but the idea is.. I am comparing the column B of sht1 and sht2. If they are same.. then I will see the corresponding q value and paste in the column q of sht1

Comment: @Jenny This macro does the exact thing that you want. Should help you out

Comment: I am getting application defined error in this line  Sheets("sht1").Cells(i, "Q").Value = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("sht1").Cells(i, "B"), _
    Sheets("sht2").Range("A1:Q" & totalrowsSht2), 17, 0)

Comment: Can you help me to figure out.

Comment: @Jenny May be you have some problem with the `_`. Can you remove that and have it in just one line

Comment: @Jenny are you using this same code? or made some changes?

Comment: I am using the same code. as it gave application defiend error, i just changed it like you said

Comment: For i = 1 to ... i used for i = 5 to.... because the data in sheet1 starts from row 5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151204/discussion-between-jenny-and-gowtham-shiva).

Comment: @Jenny Please mark the answer as correct to resolve the question

Comment: sorry, I dint check that you update the answer, i have done ti

Comment: @Jenny no worries .. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
Sheets("sht1").Range("Q5:Q" & totalrows).Value = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B5,Sheet2!$A:$Q,17,0),"""")"
```

Comment: the row is completely populated with this formula

Comment: i didnt get you?. this code is just replacement of `Sheets("sht1").Range("Q5:Q" & totalrows).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Sheets("sht1").Range("B5:B" & totalrowsSht2), Sheets("sht2").Range("$A:$Q"), 17, 0), ""`

Comment: Ya, you have given it as value with an formula. So it is just putting the formula in the cells.

Comment: I don't think it works with .value , it should be .formula

Comment: use `.formula` instead of `.Value`. and this code will write `B5` lookup value in every cell. here you have to use `.formulaR1C1` method

Comment: @Shrikant I gave it a try, it din

Comment: @MaddyNikam I will try and let you know

Comment: @MaddyNikam what is the difference between the formula and .formulaR1C1?

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165938/what-is-the-function-of-formular1c1