# Excel VBA - Table column formula - Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

Morning All,

I'm trying to create function that changes the result column in a `=VLOOKUP` formula.

```
Sub changeDay(day As Integer)
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim lo As ListObject
  Dim lColName As ListColumn

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheetName")
  Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
  Set lColName = lo.ListColumns(2)

  lColName.DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP'([@ID],'sheetName'!$A$2:$J$404," & day & ")"
End Sub
```

It returns an error `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.`

Where am I going wrong, this seems to be the accepted solution for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `FormulaR1C1` with `Formula`.

[What is the function of FormulaR1C1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165938/what-is-the-function-of-formular1c1)

Comment: It still returns `Error 1004` however when I change it to `.formula = "=sum(5)"` it works so I'm guessing there's something in the `"=VLOOKUP'([@ID],'Weekly Dispo'!$A$2:$J$404," & CStr(day) & ")"` part that it doesn't like.  I may need to escape some characters.

Comment: Got it. it was the `'` after `=VLOOKUP`.  Good old typos.  Cheers buddy.

Comment: @iShaymus - Cool, glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for anyone facing the same problem.

```
Sub changeDay(day As Integer)
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim lo As ListObject
  Dim lCol As ListColumn

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("aWorksheetname")
  Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
  Set lCol = lo.ListColumns(2)

  lColName.DataBodyRange.Formula = "=VLOOKUP([@ID],'aWorkSheetname'!$A$2:$J$404," & CStr(day) & ")"
End Sub
```