# How to apply vlookup to whole column?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make a vlookup macro that applies the vlookup formula to the whole column.
I'm stuck at this line `Range("K3").Formula = MyStringVar1` as this only work for the cell K3. Would appreciate any help given :)

```
Sub vlookDemo()
    Dim MyStringVar1 As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next

     MyStringVar1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("D3:D" & LastRow), _
      Worksheets("ProductList").Range("A4:B294"), 2, False)

    On Error GoTo 0
    If IsEmpty(MyStringVar1) Then
        ""
    End If

    Range("K3").Formula = MyStringVar1

End Sub
```

Comment: Vlookup uses a single value to lookup. You have Range("D3:D" & LastRow) ?

Comment: im pretty new to the VBA side of things, so I'm not sure if it is allowed. The code is the result of gathering what I understand, so I might be wrong on vlookup statement too..

Comment: Are you trying to apply a lookup formula to Range("K3:K" & LastRow) ? And should the first formula be  Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("D3"), _
      Worksheets("ProductList").Range("$A$4:$B$294"), 2, False) /?

Comment: @Hwee7 -   `On Error Resume Next` is not intended as a way to hide errors that you don't know how to fix, and is not a good idea, especially while learning VBA.  I'd suggest removing it, and onyl using it in situations where the error being raised is intentional.

Comment: @QHarr, lookup formula to Range("K3:K" & LastRow) >> Yes
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("D3"), _ Worksheets("ProductList").Range("$A$4:$B$294"), 2, False) ? >> This seems more correct because I need to fix the range so that it doesnt 'run'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a formula R1C1 such as as follows:

```
.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC4,ProductList!R4C1:R294C2, 2, FALSE),"""")"
```

Applying to a range becomes:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub PopulateFormulas()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        .Range("K3:K" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
                                             "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC4,ProductList!R4C1:R294C2, 2, FALSE),"""")"
    End With
End Sub
```

This results in formulas in the sheet such as:

[image: Sheet]

The first, in K3, being:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D3,ProductList!$A$4:$B$294, 2, FALSE),"")
```

These populate column K down to last row (based on column C).

R1C1 formula means relative references are used so the same formula can be applied to all the cells and will pick up column D in its own row. The lookup range  must have fixed cell references so it does not shift. The whole thing is wrapped in an IFERROR to replace error text with "" if value not found.

Some info on R1C1 is given in this question: [What is the function of FormulaR1C1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165938/what-is-the-function-of-formular1c1?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I have given you the entire code at the bottom there.

Comment: Oh the R1C1 is a type of notation.. I've learnt something new today!
And the code is working great for me. Thank you so much once again for the help :)