# using Application.WorksheetFunction.MRound and Cells.Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write excel formulas using Cells.Formula and Application.WorksheetFunction.MRound

I want to leave the formulas in the cells but it only leaves the values, not the formulas.

How do I leave the formulas in the cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application.WorksheetFunctions are not meant to be placed into cells, but will perform the calculation of a worksheet function in VBA.

If you want to place a formula into a cell you need to use one of the Formula properties, for example

```
Range("A1").Formula ' or
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165938/what-is-the-function-of-formular1c1) for an example of both.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cell.value = Application.WorksheetFunction.MRound` use `cell.formula = "=MRound"`. I.E. put the formula as you'd write it in a cell into the cell as a string.