# How to copy formula to different columns at the same time loop through a list to get different values as the input of the formula?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

i m new to VBA, need help on this issue from experts.

I splitted a BBG function into cell B1 and D1

`B1="BDS($C"D1=","PG_REVENUE","PRODUCT_GEO_OVERRIDE=G","number_of_periods=6")"`
C2 To C6 are names of stocks

It looks like this when pasted to cells
`=BDS($C2,"PG_REVENUE","PRODUCT_GEO_OVERRIDE=G","number_of_periods=6")`

As the code below, I would like to copy the formula to cell firstly `H11`, and then move 10 cells to the right to cell `R11` and paste the formula again and repeat the process.

For cell H11, i would like the formula to use `$C2` as the first argument, for R11, i want 2 to be increased to 3, so the first argument becomes `$C3`

My codes allow me to loop and paste the formula horizontally but failed to increase the count each time it moves. (All cells gives `$C6` as the input)

How can i change my codes so that the counter will increase by 1 as when it moves to the right?

```
Sub paste_formula()

Dim cp As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim m As Range

Set cp = Sheets("Control Panel")

cp.Activate


For t = 8 To 100 Step 10

  For x = 2 To cp.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

  cp.Cells(11, t).Formula = "=" & cp.Range("B1") & x & cp.Range("D1")

  Next x 
Next t

End Sub
```

I want 
At cell `H11`, `=BDS($C2,"PG_REVENUE","PRODUCT_GEO_OVERRIDE=G","number_of_periods=6")`

At cell `R11`, `=BDS($C3,"PG_REVENUE","PRODUCT_GEO_OVERRIDE=G","number_of_periods=6")`

At cell `AB11`, `=BDS($C4,"PG_REVENUE","PRODUCT_GEO_OVERRIDE=G","number_of_periods=6")`

etc

Comment: It sounds like you might find it useful to use R1C1 formula notation ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165938/what-is-the-function-of-formular1c1))

Using this style, it's possible to set an increment variable and then concat it into the formula string.

Comment: I solved the problem by using range and offset, but would like to see if this can be done in other ways